# Derivative of square of row vector by column vector

Tags: calculus

I've tried proving the result that:

$\dfrac{\partial((\mathbf{Nu})^2)}{\partial \mathbf{u}} = 2 \mathbf{N} \mathbf{uN}$.

My answer is close but not the correct one.

Let $\mathbf{N}$ be a row vector of constants with dimension $1 \times n$ and let $\mathbf{u}$ be a column vector of variables with dimension $n \times 1$.

Define $(\mathbf{Nu})^2 = (\mathbf{Nu})^T(\mathbf{Nu})$.

Hence:

\begin{eqnarray}
(\mathbf{Nu})^2 &=& \mathbf{u}^T \underbrace{\mathbf{N}^T\mathbf{N}}_{\mathbf{A}}\mathbf{u} \\
&=& \mathbf{u}^T\mathbf{Au}
\end{eqnarray}

where $\mathbf{A}$ is a square matrix of constants with dimension $n \times n$.

Use the identity $\dfrac{\partial({\mathbf{u}^T}{\mathbf{Au}})}{{d\mathbf{u}}} = (\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{A}^T) \mathbf{u}$ and the very well known identity $(\mathbf{AB})^T = \mathbf{B}^T \mathbf{A}^T$:

\begin{eqnarray}
\dfrac{\partial((\mathbf{Nu})^2)}{\partial \mathbf{u}} &=& (\mathbf{N}^T\mathbf{N} + \mathbf{N}^T\mathbf{N}) \mathbf{u} \\
&=& 2 \mathbf{N}^T\mathbf{N} \mathbf{u}
\end{eqnarray}

Where have I gone wrong?

I've also seen that the result holds for:

$\dfrac{\partial((\mathbf{Nu})^3)}{\partial \mathbf{u}} = 3 (\mathbf{N} \mathbf{u})^2 N$.

So in general:

$\dfrac{\partial((\mathbf{Nu})^n)}{\partial \mathbf{u}} = n (\mathbf{N} \mathbf{u})^{n-1} N$?

In short, can I apply a quasi-chain rule with vector-vector multiplication?